# Determine a basis in $R^4$ containing the vectors $u$, $v$ and $ w$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $u = (2, 3, 4, 4)^T$, $v = (0, 1, 2, 6)^T$
, $w = (0, 0, 1, 1)^T$.
Determine a basis in $\mathbb{R^4}$
containing the vectors $u$, $v$ and $ w$.
I thought the basis will contain only $u,v, w$ . However in answer-sheet there is another fourth vector added. My question is that how can I know the how many vectors bases will contain? Because in one question it asks for " V consists of those vectors in $\mathbb{R^4}$
in which the sum of the upper two coordinates is equal to the sum of the lower two coordinates and determine bases in $\mathbb{R^4}$ " and the answer is basis which contains 3 vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because here what is being asked to you is a basis of $\Bbb R^4$. And, since $\dim\Bbb R^4=4$, every basis of $\Bbb R^4$ has $4$ elements.

Comment: so if subspace has specific parameters then bases can contain 3 or 2 otherwise it will equal to dimension of R?

Comment: The number of elements of any basis of $\Bbb R^n$ is $n$. But a basis of a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ may well have less than $n$ vectors.

Comment: Thank you!It helped

Comment: I'm glad I could help.